# Error renaming a File in a for loop

Tags: java, android, file, file-rename, iteration

I have this code in Java. The randomName() function returns a string with (unsurprisingly) a random string.

```
File handle = new File(file);
String parent = handle.getParent();
String lastName = "";
for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
{
    lastName = parent + File.separator + randomName();
    handle.renameTo(new File(lastName));
}
return lastName;
```

I have the appropriate permissions, and when I log to logcat the randomName() function does all the strings, but upon the end of the loop `handle` appears to have a file name of the value of the first randomName() call.

Comment: I'd say it should be the value of the last `randomName()` call;

Comment: I believe it's a problem with handler, as the first renameTo returns true but the rest are false

Comment: Log the values of `lastName` in the for loop. `renameTo()` shouldn't affect the value of `lastName`.

Comment: That should make the question easier to answer :)

Comment: A--C: I logged and that part is working fine (all lastName's are unique)

I then logged values of .renameTo and found that the first is true, but the rest return false

Comment: @user2008804 If you solved it, you can make an answer to your question so other people facing the same issue can see what worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
File handle = null;
        String parent = "";
        String lastName = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                handle = new File(file);
                parent = handle.getParent();
            }
            else
            {
                lastName = parent + File.separator + randomName();
                handle.renameTo(new File(lastName));
                handle = new File(lastName);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this didn't work as expected is because once the file was renamed the first time, `handle` no longer referred to the file.  That is why the subsequent rename operations failed.  `File` represents a path name, not an actual object on disk.